# Why does mysql-connector tread YEAR(4) as Date?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

> **yearIsDateType**
>
> Should the JDBC driver treat the MySQL type "YEAR" as a java.sql.Date,
>   or as a SHORT?
>
> Default: true

Question: if `YEAR(4)` is an `Integer` in `mysql` (which it is by default), why does the `mysql-connector` java driver then tread a year value as `Date`?

I mean, is there any reason this default configuration makes sense at all?

Because: if you'd not have a close look on the database, you would assume the values of eg `2017-01-01` comes directly from the db. But instead, the db holds `2017` only as the year value, and java silently adds the first of month.

Comment: One possibility: The default behaviour may have originally been the (only) way the driver worked. Then, after it became apparent that it might not have been such a good idea they added the configuration option to change the behaviour, but left the default as the old behaviour to avoid breaking existing code.

Comment: I'm considering to vote to close as primarily opinion-based, because we can only guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what the documentation says:

> `YEAR[(2|4)]`
>
> `YEAR`
>
> If `yearIsDateType` configuration property is set to false, then the
> returned object type is `java.sql.Short`. If set to `true` (the default),
> then the returned object is of type `java.sql.Date` with the date set to
> January 1st, at midnight.

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html